# Can dll-files be used as plug and play modules

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, dll

My background is Java mainly, but this project has to be done in c#. So forgive me if I don't sound like I know exactly what I want, I may just use the wrong c# terms.

The core question: Can I use .dll-files like I can use .jar-libraries in Java?
I am fully planning on doing my own research on how to actually do it, all I need is a helping hand on where to start / if I am on the correct track.

I am building a tool that is basically performing some mining on databases.
The goal is to import a database like SQL, save it internally, do some processes on it and return the results.

These mining processes should be interchangeable. So if I pick to only use two of them, I won't have to load all 20 for example.

Is this possible with dll-files in c# / with visual studio?

My idea was to have the mining in these dll-files, then basically use them over an API. So if I pass a String to the DLL file, I would get a result back.

In Java I would do this with a .jar-library and if I want to add a new mining algorithm later, I could just put a new .jar-file in the program folder and the tool would find it and use it.

Am I on the right track to do this in c# / WPF? Would I be missing some important functionality? If I am on the wrong track, what would be the correct approach to tackle this?

Comment: You got it right. It will work like that.

Comment: I figured I would just miss some form of term to describe (or look up) what i need. Assembly is what I was after, thanks, guys!